# Android controlled raspberry car

Tags: android, remote-control

I have a project for uni which consists in a remote controlled raspberry pi car. All the hardware is on point, I only need a way to control the car. I tried controlling it by running a local site on the raspberry using python and flask which has four buttons : Forward, Left, Right, Backward. 
I have decided to develop an android app which would control the car by having the same four buttons. It should work like this: raspberry connects to the same wifi as phone (mobile hotspot in this case) and everytime i press a button in the android app, it would send the proper command to the raspberry, just like the web site version would have done;
I have no experience in programming android apps so that is why I am posting this here.

**TL;DR**
I need help in developing an android app to control an rc raspberry car (through wifi)

Comment: Please check web socket.

Answer (score 0):

**RaspberryPI:**
 Create WebSocket Server with python.
https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server

**Android:**
Connect to Raspberry PI with WebSocket.
https://trinitytuts.com/connect-to-websocket-on-android-using-okhttp/

---

WebSocket allow bidirectional communication via TCP.
We can control rapsberry pi with any command.